# Checking the Python Version with the help of CMD

Tags: python

I'm trying to check the python version with the help of CMD but it throws "python not found"

[CMD output]("E:\New folder\error\Screenshot 2023-07-22 113718.png")

I also added a path in system environment while installing IDLE.

Comment: Can you replace path on your drive with actual error?

Comment: Also, try to relaunch your cmd instance or run `refreshenv` command to sync env of cmd with system. Also, you can try to call it with `python3` or simply `py` if you are on windows

Answer (score 0):

In above question the error is due to version updation, I used updated version of CMD
Instead of this(python --version) we have to use a this (py --version) command to check the version of python in CMD